# Can 2nd Magento store (multistore) just use a directory under 1st stores /app and /skin for design?

Tags: magento

When creating a Magento multistore, can the 2nd store not just use a directory under the following locations or do symbolic links have to be created (the 2nd store does have it's own root directory due to being created as add-on domain).

```
/app/design/frontend/default/nameofskin
/skin/frontend/default/nameofskin
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on if your theme `nameofskin` is falling back to `default/default` theme. If not then just create your own package.

```
/app/design/frontend/default/nameofskin --> /app/design/frontend/your-package/default
/skin/frontend/default/nameofskin --> /skin/frontend/your-package/default
```

Then you can create additional theme within your package like

```
/app/design/frontend/your-package/second-theme
```

but skip creating a skin dir for it. In this case it will fall back to `default` theme of your package.

Comment: Ah. Makes sense Tim, thanks. I just created some symlinks a moment ago and this got it working straight away. But yes due to the way a previous developer had set this one up, theme folder was residing within the 'default' so could just create new package level with default and then stick theme within to resolve. Good to know for future and thanks very much for confirming. :)